# Keep getting SQLiteException no such column

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to update a particular row of a database, and I have the following code

```
 public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME +
        "(" + TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME + " TEXT, " + TableData.TableInfo.USER_PIN +
        " TEXT, " + TableData.TableInfo.PARTNER_FIRST + " Text, " + TableData.TableInfo.PARTNER_SECOND +
        " TEXT, " + TableData.TableInfo.DATE + " TEXT, " + TableData.TableInfo.SIGNATURE_IMAGE + " BLOB, " +
        TableData.TableInfo.PARTNER_SIGNATURE + " BLOB);";
```

And I am getting an error from

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
    CR.moveToLast();

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = DOP.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, CR.getString(0));
    args.put(TableData.TableInfo.PARTNER_FIRST, partner_name);


    SQ.update(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, args, "ROWID=?" + id, null);
```

This is the error:

```
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: partner_first (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE reg_info SET user_name=?,partner_first=? WHERE ROWID=?54
```

Here is my table info

```
public static abstract class TableInfo implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String USER_PIN = "user_pin";
    public static final String PARTNER_FIRST = "partner_first";
    public static final String PARTNER_SECOND = "partner_second";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    //public static final String LOC = "location";
    public static final String SIGNATURE_IMAGE = "signature_image";
    public static final String PARTNER_SIGNATURE = "partner_signature";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_info";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "reg_info";

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yea I've declared it like 

    public static final String PARTNER_FIRST = "partner_first";

Comment: side note: `"ROWID=?" + id` is not going to work.

Comment: @njzk2 ah right ill change it to Long.toString(id)

Comment: you tried uninstalling the app and renaming the database ?

Comment: how did you create your database? You call the "create table" string "CREATE_QUERY" but it is not a query at all.. so, please post more code

Comment: @pratz9999 i wiped all user data and not getting the error anymore

Comment: @Alex so its working ?

Comment: @pratz9999 yea it's working I would accept your comment as an answer but I don't know if I can.

Comment: @Alex i have posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Uninstall** and **rename** the database..  This happens frequently when you
>   change your table name or any change in database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your UPDATE statement - you have a concatenated string and are not passing the "WHERE" arg correctly on this line:

```
SQ.update(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, args, "ROWID=?" + id, null);
```

simply do this:

```
SQ.update(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, args, "ROWID=" + id, null);
```

the error is misleading because the SQL statement is wrong altogether.

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately